# How to generate javascript file, which can be loaded via script tag by a non nextjs web page

Tags: next.js

In my current project we are migrating an application to nextjs. Now I would like to inject a react component into a legacy page through including a script, which is using code from the new nextjs application. Her a simplified version of the script:

```js
function injectCode() {
  const container = document.getElementById("container")
  const reactRoot = createRoot(container)
 
  reactRoot.render(<ExistingComponent />)
}

document.addEventListener('load', injectCode)
```

How can I generate a js file, that can be included into a webpage not rendered by nextjs? Best would be to generate the file with `next build`, but directly running webpack would be ok as well.

Until now I tried to write my own webpack config and just run webpack directly. It would be ok if I run webpack once and check the generated file into git. Therefore the generated file is put into the public folder.
This is not the only webpack config I tried, but after too many iterations solving one problem and getting the next I gave up thinking there is probably an easier solution.

```js
module.exports = {
  entry: './script.tsx',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(ts|tsx)?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ts|tsx)?$/,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'lib'),
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'ts-loader',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ts|tsx)?$/,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'components'),
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'ts-loader',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ts|tsx)?$/,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'single-header-footer'),
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'ts-loader',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(js)?$/,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node-modules'),
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'ts-loader',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
    filename: 'next-js-component.js',
  },
}
```

I am probably missing a lot of settings which are required.

The second thing I tried was extending the webpack configuration within the next.config.js file:

```js
...
webpack: (config, { buildId, dev, isServer, defaultLoaders, nextRuntime, webpack }) => {
  const originalEntry = config.entry

  config.entry = async () => {
    const entries = await originalEntry()
    entries['next-js-component'] = ['script.tsx']
    return entries
  }
  return config
},
...
```

This creates a chunk file .next/static/chunks/next-js-component-dc0ae8d2d7a87ec9.js. But I don't know how to use this file. Probably I need to add some other code into the page which loads the created chunk and additional chunks.

The header and footer of the legacy pages are already rendered by the next.js app and are included into the page via server side include. So I might be able to use something like the HtmlWebpackPlugin to inject the correct script tag into the header, which is then included into the legacy page.